# How to populate select option dropdown with database info in django

Tags: django

I have a django project with a select dropdown. I have typed in the names of players that users can select, but i want to populate the dropdown with the same names but dynamically from the database. How can i go about this?

This is my html so far, not sure how to write the views.py for this, or if i should do a for loop or and if.

```
<form method="POST">
```

{% csrf_token %}

```
   <select id="playerselect" name="pitcher" class="player-dropdown">
    <option value="{{ pitching.id}}">{{ pitching.player_name }}</option>
    <option value="2">Yadiel Lugo</option>
    <option value="3">Cody Reeds</option>
    <option value="4" >Xavier Colon</option>
    <option value="5" >Andy Smith</option>
    <option value="6" >Carson Rex</option>
    <option value="7" >Jalen Jackson</option>
    <option value="8" >Matthew Cobbs</option>
    <option value="9" >Matt Sampson</option>
    <option value="10" >John Harrison</option>
    <option value="11" >Robert Santiago</option>
    <option value="12" >Efrain Zuniga</option>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
    </select>
```

Comment: You don't need to make form manually you can use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField
look more into https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/ and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/.
If you are going to make it manually you should pass list of objects in context and iterate over them https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In view.py get all the options that you want to see in your HTML

```
options = yourmodels.objects.filter(foo=bar)
```

Then pass it in your context dictionary

```
context = {'options': options, ...}
```

Then In Your HTML

```
<select id="playerselect" name="pitcher" class="player-dropdown">
{% for option in options %}
    <option value="{{ option.id}}">{{ option.player_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</select>
```

Comment: The return statement for the function in views would be: return(request, context) Is it correct?

Comment: return render(request, '{your html template}', context)

Comment: It works. Excelent!

Comment: @ImranRahman Now what if after populating the selector Box I want to insert the selected option into a different model how can I go about it?

Comment: @Kennerdol not really sure what you're trying to do. can you please elaborate?

Comment: @ImranRahman, For example, I have two models, Original_Model and Copy_Model, The Original_Model contains data about vehicles (e.g Mazda, Toyota, Audi, BMW, VW,). I populate the Selector Box on HTML with the data from vehicles from Original_Model which is working fine, now I want to insert the option I select from the Original model into a Copy_Model. Both models have the same atributes.