# Unable to populate select option from database in Django

Tags: mysql, django

I am a beginner to Django and unable to populate the items from my database table to `<option></option>.`

**From models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields.related import ForeignKey

# Create your models here.

class Tbl_Category(models.Model):
    cat_Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cat_Name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return [self.cat_Id, self.cat_Name]

class Tbl_Item(models.Model):
    item_Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    item_Name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    cat_Idf = models.ForeignKey(Tbl_Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_Price = models.IntegerField()
```

**From views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from orderapp.models import Tbl_Item

# Create your views here.
def displayMain(request):
    return render(request,'index.html')

def ct(request):
    options = Tbl_Item.objects.filter(cat_Idf=1)
    context = {'alloptions' : options}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**From index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css.css' %}">
    <title>DATA COLLECTION</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="order-screen">
            <div class="element">
                <label for="coffee-tea">Coffee-Tea</label>
                <select name="coffee-tea" id="coffee-tea">
                    {% for opt in alloptions %}
                    <option value="{{opt.item_Id}}">{{opt.item_Name}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
       
               <div class="cart-screen">CART-SCREEN</div>
        
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I assure you that my database connection is working absolutely fine and there was no problem while running ***makemigrations*** and ***migrate*** commands. My tables contain values that I have hardcoded. Please guide me with what is wrong with my approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly you want to have a dropdown for different options in a form. In Django this would be done on the model with `choices`
example

```
OWNERSHIP=[
    ('current owner', 'Current Owner'),
    ('past owner','Past Owner'),
    ]


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ownership = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=OWNERSHIP)
```

then just render the form field  as `{{ form.ownership }}` and it will give you a dropdown

Comment: I want to do something like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67144636/how-to-populate-select-option-dropdown-with-database-info-in-django/67145326?noredirect=1#comment123630270_67145326

Comment: so you want the data to be populated from the database?